# Can't connect to database on localhost

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Ok, I have a really stupid problem here, and I'm starting to get really upset.

Just a few minutes ago, I could run my website on localhost with no problems. It's running in apache2 on the same machine as mySQL (an Ubuntu box).

I changed PHP's timezone and file upload size limit, then restarted both apache and mysql.

Now when I try to run the site from apache on the server, it can no longer select the database. As far as I can tell, it doesn't have a problem actually connecting to mysql, but when I run mysql_selectdb, it doesn't work.

If I run this site from my laptop, connecting to it via my home network, it works flawlessly.

I'm really really frustrated right now because it was working just fine minutes ago. I don't remember even changing any mySQL settings.

Can someone please help me figure out how this happened, and how to fix it? I really need to get this working as soon as possible.

**EDIT:** Here's the code I'm using to connect:

```
mysql_connect($serverUrl,'xx','xxx');
@mysql_selectdb('mydatabase') or die(mysql_error());
```

**EDIT 2:** When I use the root user login, it works just fine. To the best of my knowledge, I have given root access to the user I was using before, but I guess I could be wrong. Here is the command I was using in mySQL to give access:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'user'@'localhost';
```

Comment: Do you get any errors when trying to select your db?

Comment: add `or die(mysql_error());` to the end of your mysql lines and run the script. That should point you in the right direction.

Comment: Try reverting your php.ini to the previous settings, and maybe post some code. Also what does selectdb return? Aren't any errors thrown?

Comment: the error is 'Access denied for user 'www-data'@'localhost' (using password: NO)' ... wtf?? the user i'm using is definitely not 'www-data'. Thank you, Grexis, for that tip. I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the user i'm using is definitely not 'www-data'.

My guess is you're using one of the `mysql_*` functions *before* you establish the connection. That will make the mySQL library use default login data - which, in your case, fail.

Check out the file name and line number of your error message to see where it gets triggered.

Comment: So is there some kind of way to wait for the connection before executing commands?

Comment: I added some code to my question. Is it the correct way to go about things? It looks to me like my code should connect first.

Comment: @Jimmy I can't tell because you're not showing what code you are running before connecting. Which line number do you get in the error message?

Comment: The error happens on the line '@mysql_selectdb('mydatabase') or die(mysql_error());' in my code. That is the only place I have the mysql_error() function in any of my code. And like I said, this same code works fine when running remotely. All I change is the $severUrl variable from '192.168.0.xxx' to 'localhost.'

Comment: @Jimmy and is that line before or after the `mysql_connect()`?

Comment: @Jimmy agh, my eyes, sorry :) And your user login is not `www-data`?

Comment: nope. I've never seen that before today. Thank you for helping out, though. I'm really freaking out right now.

Comment: @Jimmy are you in SQL Safe Mode? If so, the connection command will ignore all your input/args.

Comment: @Jimmy are you 100% sure you are sending a user name and password? Can you add the `or die...` to the `mysql_connect()`? My suspicion is that the connect call fails, and the "selectdb" call then tries to establish a connection based on default values

Comment: Ok, I'm really sorry. You're right. Access is being denied for my user. I thought for sure that I was getting connected. I remember specifically checking to see if it was connecting, but I guess in my confusion (and rage) I messed up. Now the next question is, why is my user being denied? I'm pretty sure I gave it full access...

Comment: @Jimmy if you have PHPMyAdmin on there, login and take a look at the permissions on the db

Comment: I don't have PHPMyAdmin, but I just ran GRANT ALL on the user in question a couple times, and did FLUSH PRIVILEGES.

Comment: @Jimmy Did you specify the user's domain or use `%`?

Comment: I've tried both. I specified the user exactly as the error message does: 'user'@'localhost'. No luck. :(

Comment: @Jimmy hmm, *really* strange.

Comment: Yeah. It really doesn't make any sense. I'm missing something, because things were perfectly fine just a little while ago. And that's the worst part. I know that at one point in time, there was no problem.